# Symfony2 Ddeboer bundle: replace blank with 0s

Tags: symfony, csv

How to replace all blank cells in csv file with zeros when importing to database?

For example:

This

```
title;id;rating
cream,20,,
lotion,21,3.5
```

change to:

```
title;id;rating
cream,20,0,
lotion,21,3.5
```

This is my function

```
public function importProducts(){
    $path = $this->fileLocator->locate('@MyBundle/Resources/products.csv');

    $file = new \SplFileObject($path);

    $reader = new CsvReader($file, ',');
    $reader->setHeaderRowNumber(0);

    // Create the workflow from the reader
    $workflow = new StepAggregator($reader);

    // Create a writer: you need Doctrine’s EntityManager.
    $doctrineWriter = new DoctrineWriter($this->em, 'AppBundle:Product');
    $workflow->addWriter($doctrineWriter);


    // Process the workflow
    $workflow->process();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add [a converter](https://github.com/ddeboer/data-import#callbackvalueconverter) to return 0 instead of null value:

```
public function importProducts(){
    $path = $this->fileLocator->locate('@MyBundle/Resources/products.csv');

    $file = new \SplFileObject($path);

    $reader = new CsvReader($file, ',');
    $reader->setHeaderRowNumber(0);

    // Create the workflow from the reader
    $workflow = new StepAggregator($reader);

    // Create a writer: you need Doctrine’s EntityManager.
    $doctrineWriter = new DoctrineWriter($this->em, 'AppBundle:Product');
    $workflow->addWriter($doctrineWriter);

    //Converter for null values
    $converter = new CallbackValueConverter(function ($input) {
        if(null === $input) $input = 0;
        return $input;
    });

    //Adding the converter for the desired columns
    $workflow->addValueConverter('title', $converter); 
    $workflow->addValueConverter('id', $converter); 
    $workflow->addValueConverter('rating', $converter); 

    // Process the workflow
    $workflow->process();
}
```